# Friction on a moving car

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag

When driving a car, constant velocity is achieved when there is no net force acting upon the car. But does friction increase with speed, like air resistance? What causes a car to travel at constant velocity?

In a world without air resistance, would constant velocity be achieved by applying a force to a car, to accelerate it to a desired speed, before applying less force that is equivalent to friction, so there is no net force?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, there is *no friction interacting* with the car at constant speed.

- When an object **slides** over a surface, kinetic friction appears. But it is constant (at not-too-high speeds) and doesn't depend on velocity:
  $$f_k=\mu_k n.$$

But this is not the case for driving a car. Here, nothing is sliding over a surface. Instead, the wheels are *rolling*, meaning that the contact point with the surface is stationary for a brief moment before the next point on the wheel perifery takes over.

- If you **speed up the rotation** (increased angular velocity), then the wheel will "push back" on the ground. This causes a *static friction* to appear and push *forwards*. And this is how the wheel and car can accelerate.
- If you **slow down the rotation** (decreased angular velocity), then the ground "moves faster" than the rotation and the contact point will start sliding. A static friction force appears to prevent this sliding by pushing backwards in the wheel in order to increase the rotational speed again.
- If the wheel **just rolls without acceleration at constant speed**, then *there is no static friction needed*. The wheel would (ideally) continue this rolling forever since no energy is lost. This is the key benefit of using wheels rather than sliding/draggin techniques for transportation - no energy is spent on keeping up such motion, only on changing it.

So, to the essence of your question: no, friction does **not** increase with speed (not kinetic nor static). Static friction in particular might only increase with *changes* in speed. After having applies enough force to cause enough acceleration to reach the wanted speed, then you can (ideally) stop applying any force at all. The wheels will continue at their current rotational and translational speed forever.

Comment: "If the wheel just rolls without acceleration at constant speed, then there is no static friction needed".  I could be wrong, but it seems to me the static friction force between the wheel and road is the only thing that matches the opposing forces (drag, rolling resistance, etc.) to keep the car moving at constant speed. What you said would be correct if there were no opposing forces.

Comment: @BobD Yes, agreed, that is why I point out "*ideally*" all the way through the answer. Adding your mentioned non-ideal but realistic effects will change the picture a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> What causes a car to travel at constant velocity?

A car travels at constant velocity when the torque applied to the drive wheel(s) produces a forward static friction force between the tire(s) and road that equals all of the forces opposing the forward motion of the car, for a net force of zero in the direction of motion. The two major opposing forces are drag (a.k.a. air resistance) and rolling resistance (a.k.a. rolling friction or rolling drag).

As you already know, drag increases with speed. The greater the drag the greater the required drive torque (and resulting static friction force) needed to match the drag. This is possible up until the maximum possible static friction force of $\mu_{s}N$ is reached at which point slipping/skidding and kinetic friction is impending.

> In a world without air resistance, would constant velocity be achieved
> by applying a force to a car, to accelerate it to a desired speed,
> before applying less force that is equivalent to friction, so there is
> no net force?

In a world without air resistance (and without rolling resistance and any other friction associated with the moving parts of the car), once the car accelerates to the desired speed, no static friction force is needed to keep the car moving at constant speed. There would also be no kinetic friction forces because the wheels would not be slipping/skidding on the road (as might occur due to hard acceleration or braking).

Hope this helps.